# Retornar Valores de un List c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Buenas quisiera que me puedan ayudar.

Les comento estoy realizando un webservice que me devuelve en un **List<>** , estoy usando en Dos Capas en :
1.Web Service
2.Capa Datos

El Codigo de mi Webservice es el Siguiente:

```
public class Heldesk : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        D_Usp_LlenarCombos obj = new D_Usp_LlenarCombos();
        [WebMethod]
        public List<Combos> Ws_LlenarCombo(Int32 Opt,Int32 Id_Tipo)
        {
            return obj.D_LlenarCombo(Opt, Id_Tipo);
        }
    }
```

Cree una Clase Datos para adjuntar en la List<> que tiene lo siguiente :

```
public class Combos
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public Int32 Nombre { get; set; }
    }
```

y en mi capa Datos el Siguiente:

```
  public List<Combos> D_LlenarCombo(Int32 Opt, Int32 Id_Tipo)
    {
        SqlDataReader reader;

        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ObtenerCadenaConexion());
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("LlenarCombo", cn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@opt", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Opt;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id_Tipo", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Id_Tipo;

        reader= cmd.ExecuteReader();
        List<Combos> Combo = new List<Combos>();
        try
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {

                Combo.Add(reader.GetValue(0), reader.GetValue(1));

            }
            reader.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();
            cn.Close();
            return D_LlenarCombo(Opt, Id_Tipo);
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(Ex.Message);
        }
```

Este es mi Procedimiento:

```
create procedure llenarcombos
@opt int,
@Id_Tipo int
as
if @opt=1
begin
select Id_Tipoincidencia,TipoIncidencia from Ms_TipoIncidencia

end
```

lo que deseo es que me vote este resultado

```
Id_Tipoincidencia      TipoIncidencia
    1                  Incidencia de Aplicativo
    2                  Bank Plus
    3                  Base de datos
```

El problema que no me sale los resultados ,me vota este error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si me podrian ayudar.

Lo que deseo en realidad es que consumir ese servicio y agregarlo en un combobox

Comment: cuales partes probaste y hasta donde estas seguro que anda?

Comment: Probe ejecutando el servicio pero no me arroja los datos de la Lista en el Webservice. @gbianchi

Comment: entonces tenes que empezar a debuguear por ahi.. el SP anda?

Comment: @gbianchi lo ejecute desde el SP y si funciona y me vota pero como en la List algo que no me esta retornando y en el codigo no me vota ningun error.

Comment: acabo de notar algo muy raro... esto esta mal! return D_LlenarCombo(Opt, Id_Tipo);.. en que momento estas ejecutando el query? nunca!

Comment: @gbianchi soy nuevo con List y en webservice yo se como llenar en un Dataset o Datatable pero en List pense que no se usaban. la verdad pienso que se llenan retornando nuevamente .

Comment: pero ahi estas llamando recursivamente a la funcion.. nunca ejecutas el query...

Comment: si puedes, entra al [chat]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El metodo Add del `List<T>` acepta un objeto del tipo generico especicado por lo que tienes que enviar un objeto de tipo `Combos`.

Cambia:

```
while (reader.Read()){
 Combo.Add(reader.GetValue(0), reader.GetValue(1));
}
```

Por

```
while (reader.Read()){
 Combo.Add(new Combos { Id = reader.GetInt32(0), Nombre = reader.GeString(1) });
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias @Einer como ahora lo retorno le puse 

 return Combo(); pero me salto un erro indicando que se esperaba un nombre de un metodo

Comment: me salto un error en :
 Combo.Add(new Combo { Id = reader.GetInt32(0), Nombre = reader.GetString(1) });  

new Combo indicando es variable pero se usa como tipo

Comment: en vez de `return Combo();` pon `return Combo;`

Comment: Perdon, ahora me fijo que el nombre de la clase es `Combos` no `Combo`. Mira la respuesta que la actualize.

Comment: Excelente hermano si me funciono :D